# redirect to previous page after page printed

Tags: javascript, printing

i developed a system and i have some pages that i want to print right after page loaded.

for example i want to print `USERS` page right after page was loaded, and i use this method:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  window.print();
});
```

it works but I want to redirect to previous page right after page was printed and i tried this way:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  window.print();
  history.back();
});
```

but its not work, it redirect after page was loaded, not wait to print the page then redirect to previous page

Comment: this should only works if previous page exists otherwise its not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [afterprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/afterprint_event).

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  window.onafterprint = function(){
    history.back();
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, but i don't know why its not redirect first time, when the page was loaded, the page will print but then not redirect to previous page.. 

then after i refresh page and load again, after print page redirect to previous page. so i don't know why it didn't happen first time.

Comment: Does it change something if you use `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load` for the first event ?

Comment: No, even its not going to previous page with second load.